# svn cannot delete file with @@ in its name

Tags: svn

```
benson@cn0:/u1/benson/corpora/he/walla$ svn rm "_12_@@_live.xml"
svn: '_12_@' does not exist
```

The file with the full name is in there, I got it from svn co. Now I'm trying to get rid of it.

Does anyone know how to persuade it not to stop at the first @?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757435/

Comment: Cool, I've alsmost made it there, although haven't used svn for ages ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `@HEAD` or @ to the end (after .xml). Just a guess. If that doesn't work, try the same, but using the URL to repository (e.g. `http://localhost/svn/path/file@rev` )

It seems to try to interpret the @something part as the revision.

Comment: That certainly changed the symptom. I gotta go and I'll check on this some more later.

svn: Use --force to override this restriction
svn: '_12_@@_live.xml' is not under version control