# svn add iphone4 icon

Tags: iphone, svn, macos

I have iPhone4 icons, which are terminated with @2x.png
My problem is that when I try to add them to svn with `svn add path/myIcon@2x.png` I get the error:

> svn: warning: 'path/myIcon' not found

I suppose that svn or my system do not support the "@" in the path..

What can I do?

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.4 and tried to add it directly with subversion and through svnX (which should and does give the same result). I think the repository is on a linux system.

Comment: This has a duplicate from not long ago that had a good solution IIRC. It's just hard to find....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add an extra @ at the end.

So `svn add path/myIcon@2x.png@`

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem also... my solution was to add them via SCM in Xcode. If you don't have your SCM set up, it's worth doing, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra `@` at the end of the filename (see [How to escape @ characters in Subversion managed file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757435/how-to-escape-characters-in-subversion-managed-file-names)).

Answer (score 0):

For multiply files I've used next soultion: for an example I have a folder named **images** with iPhone3 and iPhone4 images.
I just write:

```
svn add images
```

And all files (with @2x too) will be added into svn. No problems, fast.

But of course if images has some files in svn then I should add this folder again (remove current, add files and **svn add images**)