# How do I escape @ character in Mac

Tags: macos, svn

I need to check in the image file, image@2x.png in Mac. When I try to use the command,

*$ svn commit -m "another new file" image\@2x.png*

it doesn't work.

I then tried using single quote around the file name as suggested in some other answers

*$ svn commit -m "another new file" 'image\@2x.png'*

That also doesn't seem to work.

Removing the backslash before the @ also doesn't seem to work.

*$ svn commit -m "another new file" 'image@2x.png'*

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757435/how-to-escape-characters-in-subversion-managed-file-names) and to the SVN book you need to add another @ symbol to the end of the file:

```
svn commit -m "another new file" image@2x.png@
```

Give it a try and let us know if that works :D

Comment: To elaborate: It’s because svn interprets the first “@”. Adding a trailing one causes it to treat the first one literally. An alternative is to replace the “@” with “?” or “*”, assuming you don’t have more than one file that matches that pattern.