# svn commit file named "@2x.png"

Tags: ios, svn

In my iOS project, I have images ending in @2x.png, for retina resolution. I am using command line svn. When I try to add `image@2x.png` to svn repo, I do it as:

```
svn add image@2x.png
```

and then I get a warning as follows:

```
svn: warning: 'image' not found
```

Image is not added to subversion control, and I cannot commit it. "Regular image", ie. "image.png" commits fine.

What am I doing wrong? How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
svn add image@2x.png@
```

please note the last "@" sign!

Answer (score 3):

try  with following line :

```
svn add "image@2x.png"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use quotes around the filename in this case cause @ is a special marker for SVN to mark [peg-revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s03.html).

Comment: the answer was already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757435/how-to-escape-characters-in-subversion-managed-file-names, and, seriously, this answer will not do.

Answer (score 0):

pandaxcl has the correct answer. Just putting the filename in quotes doesn't work. You don't need the quotes, but you do need to add an @ at the end of the filename.

The correct answer, with documentation from the SVN manual, is here:

[How to escape @ characters in Subversion managed file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757435/how-to-escape-characters-in-subversion-managed-file-names)

Comment: It seem to be more the comment then an answer.