# intellij idea - unable to commit files contain "@" in the file names using subversion

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, version-control, intellij-14

I'm using **Subversion 1.8** within **IntelliJ Idea 14** as version control system. But I'm not able to commit files contain `@` in the file names.

Sample file name: `fancybox_loading@2x.gif`

**Getting this error:**

```
svn: E200009: a peg version is not allowed here
```

Tried to add `@` **at the end of the file name** as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071908/282855); but did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [recently fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140114) in IntelliJ 14.1.5 and 15 EAP. You should try updating your IDE.